# Angular 6 download API excel file

Tags: excel, download, angular6

I want to download an excel file on response:
this what I did :

```
download(type: string) {
 this.http.get(`download_template?template=${type}`).subscribe(data => {});
}
```

and this is what I got :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have done something similar... This is my approach below and it works.

Install npm i --save file-saver

**Service**

```
download(type: string) {
 return this.http.get(`download_template?template=${type}`, {responseType: 'blob'});
}
```

**Component**

```
...
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
...


this._service.download(type: string).subscribe(res => { 
     saveAs(res, 'YourFileName.xlsx', 
     { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' })

}}
```

Comment: How do I get the filename of excel downloaded? I don't want to provide new name `YourFileName.xlsx`.

Answer (score 1):

In your backend make an endpoint which returns the file you wanted when requesting.

In your front end use in this way

```
<a [href]=URLoftheFile download="FilenameWithExtension">DownloadFile</a>
```